# Separating and Dropping stringed data from a column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython

Hello If i have a column in a data frame like this:

```
df["OriginCityName"]: 
                        OriginCityName:
    0                  Dallas/Fort Worth, TX
    1                  Detroit, MI
```

I wish to extract the Words "Dallas" and "Detroit" only and drop the remaining data.I want the column to look like this after:

```
df["OriginCityName"]: 
                         OriginCityName:
        0                  Dallas
        1                  Detroit
```

Is there any way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `extract` method with regex `(^[A-Za-z]+)`. This extracts all alpha characters from the beginning of the string:

```
df.OriginalCityName.str.extract('(^[A-Za-z]+)')

#0
#0     Dallas
#1    Detroit
#Name: OriginalCityName, dtype: object
```

Or if you are sure what you want to extract comes before either `/` or `,`, you can try this one: `df.OriginalCityName.str.extract('(^.*?)(?=[/,])')`. This extracts everything before the first `/` or `,` due to lazy match `.*?`.

Comment: And good luck with New York, but that's another story than OP's one :)

Comment: @StevenG There are a lot of resources about regex online. I think this blog from another stack overflow user is a good start. There are four parts of tutorial in total. https://rock321987.wordpress.com/2016/06/19/regex-tutorial-part-1/

Answer (score 2):

Because the rules for how you want city names to be "cleaned up" might evolve as you see more data, I'd build a cleanup function. In this case, `re.split` should do the trick, and be extensible over time:

```
import re

name_clean = lambda name: re.split(r'[/,]', name)[0]
df.OriginCityName = df.OriginCityName.apply(name_clean)
```

Using `re.split` has the virtue of properly handling cities with spaces or punctuation in their names, such as `"New York"` and `"St. Petersburg"`.

[image]